# Selenium phpunit: How to check for valid html page

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

Is there some function for checking is any html page is valid?
10x

Comment: What do you mean by the valid page?

Comment: If document is XHTML than you can use XML schema (XSD) to validate document - DOMDocument::schemaValidate